# The use of ":" and "->" in AutoLISP

Tags: autolisp

```
;;----------------=={ Add Objects to Block }==----------------;;
;;                                                            ;;
;;  Adds all objects in the provided SelectionSet to the      ;;
;;  definition of the specified block.                        ;;
;;------------------------------------------------------------;;
;;  Author: Lee Mac, Copyright © 2011 - www.lee-mac.com       ;;
;;------------------------------------------------------------;;

(defun LM:AddObjectstoBlock ( doc block ss / lst mat )

    (setq lst (LM:ss->vla ss)
          mat (LM:Ref->Def block)
          mat (vlax-tmatrix (append (mapcar 'append (car mat) (mapcar 'list (cadr mat))) '((0. 0. 0. 1.))))
    )
    (foreach obj lst (vla-transformby obj mat))

    (vla-CopyObjects doc (LM:SafearrayVariant vlax-vbobject lst)
        (vla-item (vla-get-Blocks doc) (cdr (assoc 2 (entget block))))
    )
    (foreach obj lst (vla-delete obj))
    (vla-regen doc acAllViewports)
```

This is the first time I have seen this type of syntax being used in AutoLISP.

I am trying to get some explanation of what `"LM:"` actually means.

The use of `"Ref->"` is also a question for me. `"Ref"` does not seem to be defined so it seems it must be part of the system somehow although I could not pull out any documentation describing such use of `"Ref->"`.

Why is the local variable `ss` being accessed with `"LM:ss->"`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of syntax is not construction of AutoLISP/Visual LISP. it's Lee Mac's standard. I understand it in this way:

"LM:" actually means shortcut of "Lee Mac" ;)

(LM:ss->vla ss) shound switch datatype from selection set to list of vla-objects where selection set is something simmilar to list of selected elements, but defined as type entity, not vla-object. Maybe get by (ssget) or (ssgetfirst)

(LM:Ref->Def block) get block definition based on it's reference. where "LM:Ref->Def" is only full name of function. "Ref" is not any kind of variable, it's part of function name.

"LM:ss->" not means that we use ss defined as parameter of function, but "LM:ss->vla" is name of function.

Comment: I finally understood after looking at the name of the function which includes "->". So I think there may be an "=>" as part of LISP but not an actual "->" which is a Lee Mac convention.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a function in AutoLISP, the only naming convention which imparts an alternative behaviour on the resulting function is the prefix `c:`

*For example:*

```
(defun c:test ( )
    (princ "\nHello World!")
    (princ)
)
```

The use of the `c:` prefix in the function name means that the function may be evaluated as a command directly at the AutoCAD command-line.

Here, typing `test` at the AutoCAD command-line would cause `Hello World!` to be printed on a new line in the command-line window.

If the function was instead defined as:

```
(defun test ( )
    (princ "\nHello World!")
    (princ)
)
```

Typing `test` at the AutoCAD command-line would result in the error message:

`Command: test Unknown command "TEST".  Press F1 for help.`

For the function to be evaluated, the user would instead need to type: `(test)`.

---

With this in mind, the use of `LM:` has no other meaning than identification as a function from my library, and to decrease the probability that a function of the same name will be defined within the same namespace.

For example, if I were to define a function such as:

```
(defun AddLine ( pt1 pt2 )
    (entmakex
        (list
           '(0 . "LINE")
            (cons 10 pt1)
            (cons 11 pt2)
        )
    )
)
```

Given the generic naming of this function and ubiquitous operation that it performs (at least where AutoCAD is concerned), there may well be another such function with the same name defined within the Document Namespace.

Consequently, the existing function would be redefined when the above `defun` expression is evaluated, or the existing function would redefine the above function if its own `defun` expression were to be evaluated later.

By prefixing the function name with my own author prefix `LM:`:

```
(defun LM:AddLine ( pt1 pt2 )
    (entmakex
        (list
           '(0 . "LINE")
            (cons 10 pt1)
            (cons 11 pt2)
        )
    )
)
```

I am helping to ensure that when I evaluate `LM:AddLine` within the Document Namespace, my own definition of this function will always be used, and there is less chance that I could 'contaminate' the definition of a function used by another loaded program.

---

Similarly, the use of `->` within the function name is purely a naming convention and imparts no other meaning to the function.

For example, I have named my function `LM:ss->vla` because it is a standard function [from my library](http://lee-mac.com/selectionsettolist.html) which converts a Selection Set (which I've abbreviated `ss`) to a list of VLA-Objects.